# django template variable in <a>

Tags: python, django

How can i add a django template variable to href attribute of  tag?something like this

```
 <a href="{{meeting.meeting.url}}">{{meeting.meeting_url}}</a>
```

meeting.url stores a link to another website such as google etc and it is saved in database
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should pass your meeting model object to your template view

Comment: i alreay have!meeting is a model object in template!i need to somehow display meeting.meeting_url in <a> so the link works correctly!for example www.google.com

Comment: Can you show your view?

Comment: in my view i send a meeting object to my html and i want to display meeting.meeting_url in a link(meeting_url is a filed in my model meeting which keeps a url like www.google.com)all i need is to know how to display this meeting_url in my html that the link works(when user clicks on in it goes to google.com for instance1)

Comment: when i click on the link i get this url : http://127.0.0.1:8000/meeting/meeting-info/www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

To render meeting.meeting_url in your template you need to pass the meeting object as argument of the render function in your view.

More about the render function [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)

Here's an example of what should be done:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Meeting

def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    context = {'meeting': Meeting.objects.first()} # first is an example, put whatever you want
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context)
```

You must make sure that your url ([www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) does start by a / because it would refer to the root url of your website (127.0.0.1:8000) which redirects you to 127.0.0.1:8000/meeting/meeting-info/www.google.com